# KerberosSecurityTokenProvider .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, token, kerberos

is any replacement in .net core 2.x for Kerberos token generation?

I found solution in old framework in KerberosSecurityTokenProvider and method GetToken but can't find any similar function in .net core 2.1.